# PowerBI with Enbedded PowerApp - cannot edit

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerbi-powerapps

I have a PowerBI report authored in the June 2020 release of PowerBI desktop. It is a simple PowerBI report with one table on the canvas direct querying a SQL Azure database. I then added a simple PowerApp (see screen shot) and published to PowerBI service. Everything worked great.

Now when I come to edit the PowerApp I am prompted to Open Browser with a link that appears to be for the PowerApp (see the second screen shot below). I click OK and my browser opens, but I don't get to the PowerApp, I get to the default create an App Page (see 3rd screen shot). If I try open the App I get a version conflict (4th screen shot). I am accessing the PowerApp through the browser, so Microsoft is controlling the Version of PowerApps. If I fiddle around I can edit and publish the App but it seems either very convoluted or I have got the wrong end of the stick and am missing a trick. Also, when editing in the PowerApp editor, the PowerBI Integration returns no data and gives me a blank data list whereas when I created the App I could see the data.

*Side question* - does everyone else experience the same (i.e. it is just flaky), or am I doing something wrong? How do I get a slick edit experience?

*Main Question* - how do I get to see my data when editing the PowerApp?

Screen shots below.

**My Simple PowerBI report and PowerApp**

[image]

**When I click Edit (to edit the PowerApp from PowerBI)**

[image]

**Clicking Edit in PowerBI lands me here**

[image]

**I am asked to Change my PowerApps version**

[image]

**When I edit, my data is not available**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a limitation.

[From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/powerapps-custom-visual):

> Power Apps in Power BI Desktop provides data to Power Apps Studio when
> creating apps but not while editing. Use Power BI Web to preview the
> data while editing apps.

Comment: This is the only hit I got when searching for a solution for this exact issue. Does anyone have any workaround?